# Trying to remove white spaces in python .replace not working

Tags: python, string, replace

For some reason string.replace(" ", "") is not working.
Is there another way of removing white spaces from a string?
Why is .replace not working in this particular situation?

```
string = input('enter a string to see if its a palindrome: ')
string.replace(' ', '')  # for some reason this is not working 
                         # not sure why program will only work with no spaces
foo = []
bar = []

print(string)
for c in string:
    foo.append(c)
    bar.append(c)

bar.reverse()
if foo == bar:
    print('the sentence you entered is a palindrome')
else:
    print('the sentence you entered is not a palindrome')
```

Comment: strings are not mutable. `str.replace()` produces a *new* string object, but you are ignoring the return value.

Comment: As a side note, you can use slice notation to make this alot easier. Something like this will tell you if you have a palindrome `if string == string[::-1]: `

Answer (score 5):

`replace()` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the original. Try this instead:

```
string = string.replace(" ", "")
```